# Поиск скрытого компонента (Visible = false)

Tags: c#, winforms, menu, menuitem

После `InitializeComponent();` скрываю пункты MenuStrip. Делаю это следующим образом:

```
string[] elementNames = new string[] {"name1", "name2", "name3"}
foreach (var name in elementNames)
{
    var menu_item = msMainMenu.Items.Find(name, true);
    menu_item[0].Visible = false;
}
```

Далее, когда я хочу показать какой либо пункт меню, поиск не находит этот элемент т.е.:

```
var menu_item = msMainMenu.Items.Find("name1", true);
(menu_item.Count() == 0) = true;
```

Конечно, как вариант, элементы, на которые изначально воздействовал цикл, можно убрать в массив, затем обращаться уже к нему. Но есть ли ещё какие-нибудь варианты получить экземпляр компонента имея только его имя `ToolStripMenuItem.Name` и при `ToolStripMenuItem.Visible = false`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приведите просто к нужному типу.

Например код скрытия можно написать так:

```
string[] elementNames = { "name1", "name2", "name3" };

foreach (ToolStripItem item in msMainMenu.Items)
{
    item.Visible = !elementNames.Contains(item.Name);
}
```

А обратиться к определенному объекту так:

```
var item = msMainMenu.Items.Cast<ToolStripItem>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Text == "name1");
if (item != null) item.Visible = true;
```

Везде как видите стоит `ToolStripItem` - это тот объект, который содержится в `MenuStrip`, значит смело указываем нужный тип и работаем с объектом на прямую, без `Find()`.

Если же вы хотите работать с `Find`, то смотрите что именно этот метод вам возвращает.
Строка `var menu_item = msMainMenu.Items.Find("name1", true);` вернет вам `ToolStripItem[]`, то есть массив объектов и если вы уверены, что там будет один ваш объект с нужным именем, то обращайтесь через индекс (`menu_item[0].Visible = true;`) или берите с помощью LINQ первый объект (`menu_item.FirstOrDefault().Visible = true;`). Не забудьте только обработать вариант с NULL!

Comment: Первый вариант хорошо работает, но загоняет в определённые рамки. К примеру если у меня будет сложное разветвлённое меню, то придётся добавлять в коде цикл в каждый `menu_item.HasDropDown`, что не универсально. По этому я и остановился на Find. Но с ним у меня проблема, когда я ставлю `ToolStripItem.Visible = false`, то после этого Find его не возвращает. Всегда NULL.

Comment: Т.е Find возвращает 0 элементов...

Comment: В общем остановился на первом Вашем варианте. Только добавил рекурсию на каждый `menu_item.HasDropDown = true`. Спасибо за ответ!